# allowing only gmail domain

Tags: php, email, gmail

I want to allow only gmail domain emails, to register to my site, as you see below my code, allows all other email domains except gmail domain, I want the opposite.

```
if(preg_match("[@gmail.com$]", trim($request->email))){
        $notify[] = ['error', 'this domain is not allowed.'];
        $notify[] = ['info', 'Only Gmail domain is allowed.'];
        return back()->withNotify($notify)->withInput($request->all());
```

Comment: There is no need to <H1> and **bold** your post ..  We can read, and it's considered YELLING ..

Comment: Invert the condition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And simply inverse the if with a `!` --  `if(!preg_match("[@gmail.com$]",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to invert you expression.

```
if(!preg_match("[@gmail.com$]", trim($request->email))){
    $notify[] = ['error', 'this domain is not allowed.'];
    $notify[] = ['info', 'Only Gmail domain is allowed.'];
    return back()->withNotify($notify)->withInput($request->all());
}
```